# how to return an argument using sscanf

Tags: c

I am reading a line at the time from a text file that has this format: 2.34 4.68 5.98. I want to store these float values in an array so that I can make use of each argument later on but once I use sscanf and try to print the argument I get 0. Any idea what’s the problem is. Thank you.

```
    char* line[2000];
    char* State[2000];
    sscanf(line[12],"%f", &State[12]).
    printf("\n state 1: %2.3f", &State[0]);// this suppose to print 2.34 but it prints 0
```

Comment: Have you allocated any memory for all your `char *`s ? You also seem to be very confused about `float` versus `char *` ?

Comment: `char* State[2000];` should be `float State[2000];`

Comment: you need a loop to read all the states. BTW It seems like you have no idea how arrays work, you should read a book.

Comment: Your data types are really confusing ... did you intend to have 2000 pointers to strings (char arrays)? Or 2000 pointers to floats? Or just 2000 floats?

Answer (score 2):

You can scan them all at once:

```
float state[3];
if(sscanf(line[12], "%f %f %f", &state[0],
      &state[1], &state[2]) != 3) {
  ...
} else
  printf("\n state1: %f, state2: %f, state3:%f",
      state[0], state[1], state[2]);
}
```

At the moment you're scanning into one place (`State[12]`) and expecting the value to be stored somewhere else (`State[0]`).

A few more mistakes you're making:

- Storing into a `char *` array when you should be storing into a `float` array
- Using pointers with `printf` when it expects to take in actual values
- Using `.` to end a statement...? Not sure if this is a typo

Comment: ... not to mention `scanf()` needs an address, not an address of an address (`&state[12]` should just be `state[12]` if state is `float * state[2000]` (*and* the memory is allocated).

Comment: @Jamie: I think it's a little optimistic to assume his `float *` array has been initialised :)

Comment: Many thanks Mike kwan for your very explanatory reply, your comments are very useful and helpful. I highly appreciate your excellent skills.

Answer (score 1):

```
sscanf(line[12],"%f", &State[12]).
```

OK. You win a prize for having a new (at least to me) way of misunderstanding how arrays work in c.

1. You almost certainly don't want the `[12]` in either case here.

   The name of an array (either `line` or `State`) can be automatically converted to a `char*` which points at the beginning of the array. So

   ```
   sscanf(line,"%f", ...);
   ```

   scans the contents of `line`. How ever `line[12]` is a the **single character** at the position `(*line)+12`.
2. You need a `float` to put the result in *or* you need to change your format specifier from `%f` to `%s`. You should never but the results of a `%f` into a `char*`.

Comment: Thank you dmckee for your explanation. I will take you comments into consideration. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are puting the number in 12th case of your table ; that's strange.

Is it not easier to use fscanf directly ?

```
FILE *fp = fopen(fileName);
float tabNumbers[3] = {0};

if (fp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        fscanf(fp, "%f", &tabNumbers[i]);
    fclose(fp);
}
```